# Generate random number not working

Tags: jquery, random

I am trying to generate random numbers using jQuery.

However, it didn't generate them when I refresh the broswer.

My HTML follows:

```
<td colspan="3" id="number1" class="numberStyle"><span>1</span></td>
<td colspan="3" id="number2" class="numberStyle"><span>2</span></td>
```

My script follows:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
var num1;
var num2;

num1=Math.floor((Math.random()*3)+1);
document.getElementById("number1").innerhtml = num1;

num2=Math.floor((Math.random()*3)+1);
document.getElementById("number2").innerhtml = num2;

});
```

Comment: `innerHTML` not `innerhtml`

Comment: Oh there it is. Thanks alot.

Comment: Advice for the future: press F12, open console and look what the errors are. It should be clear in this case that innerhtml was undefined.

Comment: @kamilk i always use developer tools under google chrome to attempt to debug. but for this situation, it keep showing "missing ;" so i really couldnt solve it. But i will try try harder next round. Really thank you so much. Im new to jquery and i will continue to work hard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a typo,

Change your code,

```
num1=Math.floor((Math.random()*3)+1);
document.getElementById("number1").innerhtml = num1;
```

to

```
num1=Math.floor((Math.random()*3)+1);
document.getElementById("number1").innerHTML = num1;
```

It's **innerHTML** not innerhtml.

Comment: Thanks all, i got it!!

Comment: @herblackcat : Can you please accept answer if you are satisfied with my answer.

Answer (score 0):

please use the following code because you are not able to change text inside the `td` but you can change inside `Span`

**HTML**

```
<td colspan="3" id="number1" class="numberStyle"><span span class="replaceme">1</span></td>
<td colspan="3" id="number2" class="numberStyle"><span span class="replaceme2">2</span></td>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var num1;
var num2;

num1=Math.floor((Math.random()*3)+1);
$(".replaceme").text(num1);

num2=Math.floor((Math.random()*3)+1);
$(".replaceme2").val(num2);
});
```